# Premiere Pro black bars on export

Tags: export, output, adobe-premiere

I keep getting black bars on the sides and occasionally on the top and bottom as well. I've been troubleshooting the issue for at least 4 days to no avail. I tried, cropping on export pane, different settings/aspect ratios, new sequences with different settings and Scale to Fit/Fill.

The only settings that got rid of the black bars was changing the pixel ratio to 1.0 but that made my video very blurry.

My sequence settings are same FPS 1920/1080 with matching pixel ratio of 1.0 (to the imported clips). And original clips are all 1920/1080 I don't know what their pixel ratio is but when I import them to Premiere they are all 1.0

These are the export settings
https://i.gyazo.com/af4d2459228bfaad5d86864cb1263aa3.png

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of your title I'm going to assume you're uploading to YouTube? If that's so, you might try using one of the 'Presets' other than custom. If you scroll all the way down, in the preset dropdown, I remember there being options to optimise for YouTube 240/480/720/1080 and so on. This might change what you need to change.

Alternatively, I've made the mistake before of aligning my clips to the 'focus lines' rather than to the edge of the screen. Your solution may be as simple as transforming your clips bigger.

I know this is pretty late to the party. I hope you found what you were looking for.